# How do I use WebGL drawElements offset?

Tags: javascript, webgl

This is a rather WebGL specific question. I am having trouble understanding the WebGL-specific implementation of drawElements. Here is the API specification. [From the WebGL specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/).

How exactly do I use the offset? Can I use the offset to mimic the more classic glDrawRangeElements?

> void **drawElements**(GLenum mode, GLsizei count, GLenum type, GLintptr offset)
>   (OpenGL ES 2.0 §2.8, man page)
>
> *Draw using the currently bound element array buffer. The given offset is in bytes, and must be a valid multiple of the size of the given type or an INVALID_OPERATION error will be generated; see Buffer Offset and Stride Requirements. If count is greater than zero, then a non-null WebGLBuffer must be bound to the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding point or an INVALID_OPERATION error will be generated.*

I have a flat vertices array and a flat indices array, and drawing using one drawElements call has been working out great, but now I want to draw parts of the vertices separately because they are different objects. For instance, indices[0] to indices[99] is one object (e.g. an arm), and indices[100] to indices[149] (e.g. a leg) is another object. The groups must be drawn separately - ultimately because they have different textures, and I will bind a texture before each drawElements call (maybe there is another way to do this altogether?)

Thus, I want to call drawElements on indices[0] to indices[99], and drawElements on indices[100] to indices[149]. Can I do that with the drawElements offset?

With the code I have here, I can draw the first group very nicely, but the rest of the groups don't show up.

```js
for(var g = 0; g < groups.length; g++) {
    var group = groups[g];

    //Set the texture
    var material = group.material;
    material.bindTexture();

    //Draw it!
    var offset = group.offset; //index of the first element of the indices, (e.g. position '0' or position '100', from above)
    var num_items = group.num_items; //number of items in this group, (e.g. '100' elements or '50' elements, from above)
    gl.drawElements(draw_mode, num_items, indices.type, offset);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation says:

> ... The given offset is in bytes, and must be a valid multiple of the size
>   of the given type ...

If `indices.type` is `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT` then 2 bytes are been used for each index.

Try using `offset * 2` instead of just `offset`:

```
gl.drawElements(draw_mode, num_items, indices.type, offset * 2);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, Juan! I'm still rather new to StackOverflow. =)

Comment: Really perfect! You've helped me out! Thanks.